# How to default select dynamic dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code I have listed some users record. There one column to change the `produced by` that column exist one dropdown. My `ng-change` working fine. after page refresh the dropdown not populated which i was change last time. Please check my code -

Identity

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="model_produced_by" style="width: 62px;" ng-change="change_produced_by(model_produced_by, order.Order.id)">
     <option value="">Select Produced By</option>
     <option ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}" ng-selected="option.id == order.Order.assigned_to">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Output -

```
<select ng-change="change_produced_by(model_produced_by, order.Order.id)" style="width: 62px;" ng-model="model_produced_by" id="repeatSelect" name="repeatSelect" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
   <option value="">Select Produced By</option>
   <option ng-selected="option.id == order.Order.assigned_to" value="1" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Outsourced</option>
   <option ng-selected="option.id == order.Order.assigned_to" value="2" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">In-House</option> 
  <option ng-selected="option.id == order.Order.assigned_to" value="3" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Local Store/Printer</option>
</select>
```

I want to select value which is equal with `option.id == order.Order.assigned_to` But my code is not working. 
Also I have used `ng-init` in the `select` tag. The last option is showing in every dropdown. Please check and say me where is error.

[image]

Comment: In the select tag you use ng-model, where the selected value should be stored and in the each of option you placed condition: ng-selected="option.id == order.Order.assigned_to". It seems like a mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use simply [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and ngModel:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" style="width: 62px;" 
    ng-model="order.Order.assigned_to"         
    ng-change="change_produced_by(model_produced_by, order.Order.id)"
    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in produced_by.availableOptions">
     <option value="">Select Produced By</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Working Fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For the correct operation of select, you need to specify the property ng-modal, look at this example:

```
<select id="inptAdmin" name="inptAdmin" class="form-control" 
  ng-model="res.adminUser.id" ng-options="user.id as user.name + ' - ' + user.email for user in listUser" required="required">
</select>
```

In my controller i own a property listUser, which has a list of user objects, but in the ng-options i specify that want to use the id of these objects as the value, and in the ng-modal  specify where it will be saved the value select. In this example, if ' res.adminUser.id ' from filled, will select automatically the corresponding value in the select.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know angular js but I understand your problem. If you can somehow perform this operation you will get rid of your problem. You need to generate following dropdown html for selected option 2:

```
<select ng-change="change_produced_by(model_produced_by, order.Order.id)" style="width: 62px;" ng-model="model_produced_by" id="repeatSelect" name="repeatSelect" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
   <option value="">Select Produced By</option>
   <option value="1" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Outsourced</option>
   <option ng-selected="true" value="2" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">In-House</option> 
  <option value="3" ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Local Store/Printer</option>
</select>
```

If you can generate html at run time as per your condition you can do so....Here sample way i am writing your code might defferent in angular:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="model_produced_by" style="width: 62px;" ng-change="change_produced_by(model_produced_by, order.Order.id)">
     <option value="">Select Produced By</option>
     <option ng-repeat="option in produced_by.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}" (option.id == order.Order.assigned_to) ? ng-selected="true":"">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Hope this solve your problem.